# Impact of several .NET class libraries on the startup time of an application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

How much impact does the amount of class libraries have on the startup time of .NET applications?

What I mean is, having a .NET project with 100 class libraries compared to a project with 10 class libraries where in both cases the same source code is within these libraries.
Possible scenario: Splitting up independent features into independent class libraries (all layers - logic, db, etc.) instead of sub folders (for reasons of clarity & dependency management).

Is there any known impact on having a lot of class libraries to the startup time of .NET applications? Does .NET load class libraries in parallel if possible?

That there is some overhead with more assembly information etc. is obvious but is it significant enough to measure it on the startup time?

Comment: The answers already show different aspects. One thing to point out is that you can always use ILMerge or ILRepack to merge assemblies before deployment. You can also test out by merging them how much performance you gain easily. It is kind of best practice to split your code base into a few meaningful assemblies (not too many though, as that goes to another extreme).

Comment: Reboot your machine and start your program.  If it seems to take unusually long to get it going, seconds, but not the second time you start it then you'll know what caused it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say it is an early micro-optimization. This overhead is insignificant in most cases.

If you don't have problems with performance right now, then don't mind about it, just use any approach which makes your architecture more clear, transparent and convenient for developers to work with.

When you stumble upon the problem of performance and slow application startup someday, then you will start to diagnose reasons and benchmark different ways to improve performance, including reducing the number of assemblies, dynamic assemblies loading etc. This benchmark will show you precisely if any of these techniques worth it or not.

One important note: large number of assemblies affects build time which slows development and CI processes down as well.

Comment: Thank you! I think the development process should not be that much impacted if Visual Studio really builds only changed projects & dependencies (what it should do as far as I know).
Anyways, I will try it.

Answer (score 2):

To add to [Yeldar Kurmangaliyev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3218692/yeldar-kurmangaliyev)'s answer, the number of assemblies required by the application doesn't *necessarily* directly slow down your application startup. The reason for this is a bit complicated but essentially .NET and the JIT (Just In Time) compiler only load those assemblies required to execute the current branch of code.

If in order to execute a method and it's the first time that the execution has encountered it, the JIT will scan the block of IL, pull in any other references needed and fully compile it to native code to execute. Once it's done this, then the method doesn't need to be recompiled again and it will have loaded in any referenced assembly - assuming it wasn't already there in the first place.

E.g., if you're starting code was simple;

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Something");
}
```

Then the only loaded assemblies/namespaces at that point in time are those for the `System` namespace while `Main` is being executed.

If you added code to call out into another assembly then...;

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // only the core .NET assemblies loaded so far...
    Console.WriteLine("Something");

    // call a method using another assembly's components/objects...
    CallToAnotherAssembly();
}

private static void CallToAnotherAssembly()
{
    // in order for the JIT to execute this, it needs to load the
    // other assembly into memory and create the object. NOW it's
    // in memory and affecting your startup
    var objectInAnotherAssembly = new ObjectInAnotherAssembly();
}
```

In debug you can test the behaviour by calling `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetLoadedModules()` at various points to see what is and isn't loaded at that point in time.

If your application uses only a small number of methods at startup then it's not necessarily loading the other assemblies at that point in time. If it uses other components after button clicks, etc, then those modules get loaded the first time they're hit.